WinAppForms chart1.Series.Points not setting Sheet.Range("a21:a2100").Value
Private Sub ChartButton1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChartButton1.Click
        Dim TnTBooks As Workbooks
        Dim TnTSheets As Sheets
        Dim TnTSheet As Worksheet


        Dim TimeRange As Object

        Dim PriceRange As Object
        TnTBooks = TnT.Workbooks
        TnTSheets = TnT.Worksheets
        TnTSheet = TnTSheets(1)


        TimeRange = TnTSheet.Range("a21").Value

        PriceRange = TnTSheet.Range("b21").Value

        Me.Chart1.Series("Time").Points.AddXY(TimeRange, PriceRange)


    End Sub

The code above sets only one data point with x = a21 and y = b21 on my worksheet. I want to set all the data points in column a21:a2100 for the x value, and b21:b2100 for y values
I've tried code as above, but I get one point only. I want to the series to have 2079 points
ie
TimeRange = TnTSheet.Range("a21:a2100").Value
PriceRange = TnTSheet.Range("b21:b2100").Value
This above code does not work

Error:System.ArguementException: Series data points do not support
values of type System.Object[]

